# HtmlUnit read youtube chat

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to read youtube chat messages using HtmlUnit

```
@Test
void test() throws IOException {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=" + id);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(2000);


        DomNodeList<DomElement> elementsByTagName = page.getElementsByTagName("yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer");

        System.out.println(elementsByTagName.size());
    }
}
```

`String id` is a youtube livestream containing (!) chat messages

Running this will never return any elements with the tag `yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer`. I have tried various wait() methods without any success. I have noticed that in the browser the page seems to load twice and only at the end starts displaying the chat.

Comment: Any log output?

Comment: No error but hundreds of other warning and info output as is normal with htmlUnit. I am pretty sure the page is stuck at the initial opening page and never loads any of the chat elements.